# Clicking [Flutter-Open for Editing in Android Studio] nothing happens

Tags: flutter, dart

Clicking [Flutter-Open for Editing in Android Studio] nothing happens.
Android Studio is already installed.
There are also no error messages.
Editor: IDEA

doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.556], locale zh-CN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[!] HTTP Host Availability
    X HTTP host https://maven.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: 信号灯超时时间已到

    X HTTP host https://cloud.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: 信号灯超时时间已到


! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

xx_android_.iml exist, does the content need to be modified?
xx_android_.iml exist, does the content need to be modified?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
        <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
        <option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_APT" value="/gen" />
        <option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_AIDL" value="/gen" />
        <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/res" />
        <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/assets" />
        <option name="LIBS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/libs" />
        <option name="PROGUARD_LOGS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/proguard_logs" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/app/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/app/src/main/kotlin" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 29 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Flutter for Android" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="KotlinJavaRuntime" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: do u have the file under android folder "[project_name]_android.iml"

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan yes,I have written the iml content in the question.